# How do I add my PC's current date and time into SQL Server Database column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a code in which I am inserting data into SQL server using querystring method which is something as shown below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.QueryString["x"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["y"] != null)
            {
                insertData();
            }
        }
     //   else
      //  {
     //         Response.Redirect("http://localhost:53627/Default.aspx");
     //   }


    }
    public void insertData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test(x, y) VALUES(@x, @y)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("x", Request.QueryString["x"]));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("y", Request.QueryString["y"]));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
                Response.Write("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //sets the connection string from the web config file "ConnString" is the name of the Connection String
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Now in this current code I need to add date and time of my system along with the x and y values....any guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a column to table test, lets call it CreatedDate and set the [default](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) value to [GETDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

> **DEFAULT**
>
> Specifies the value provided for the column when a value is not
>   explicitly supplied during an insert. DEFAULT definitions can be
>   applied to any columns except those defined as timestamp, or those
>   with the IDENTITY property. If a default value is specified for a
>   user-defined type column, the type should support an implicit
>   conversion from constant_expression to the user-defined type. DEFAULT
>   definitions are removed when the table is dropped. Only a constant
>   value, such as a character string; a scalar function (either a system,
>   user-defined, or CLR function); or NULL can be used as a default. To
>   maintain compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server, a
>   constraint name can be assigned to a DEFAULT.
>
> **GETDATE()**
>
> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value
>   without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the
>   operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server
>   is running.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c0db/1)

As an after thought, if you wanted to send the DateTime value from C#, you could change your code to something like this, using [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.now.aspx)

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the local time.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test(x, y, dt) VALUES(@x, @y, @dt)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("x", Request.QueryString["x"]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("y", Request.QueryString["y"]));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("dt", DateTime.Now));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: No, if you set the default value of the column, and you specify the columns for inserting and leave out the date column, it will apply the default value. Or as I stated in my edit, you could also add the value from C# if you wish.

Comment: So in c# case the data type in SQL would be datetime?